# Why isn't the Move function in Character Controller not moving my player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a player model with a character controller attached and to manage the player movement I have this file below:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterMovementController : MonoBehaviour {
    Animator characterAnimator;
    CharacterController character;
    [SerializeField] Transform mainCamera;
    [SerializeField] float sprintBoost = 10f;
    [SerializeField] float currentSpeed = 20f;
    [SerializeField] float trueSpeed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start() {
        characterAnimator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
        character = gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update() {
        // There was a bunch of animation stuff that I figured wouldn't be important for
        // you to read

        Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * trueSpeed, 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * trueSpeed);
        // Movement Logic
        character.Move(move * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of the component]

I already tried to drag the currentSpeed of the player to insane numbers and still nothing works. I checked that the character controller is properly being referenced and the Move function is being passed in a Vector3 object

Answer (score 1):

So apparently it was all about the Step offset, I had a large model which I had to scale down a lot meaning the offset had to be suer low, in the end I made it 0.01

Comment: I had the same issue with my character controller not moving for some frames at start when applying acceleration. The default step offset was `0.3`. Reducing it to `0.2` did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do not multiply the input value (`Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")` or `Input.GetAxis("Vertical")`) with the speed in the `move` field, multiply it with the overall vector instead:

```cs
Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
// Movement Logic
character.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * trueSpeed);
```

Refer to the [`CharacterController.Move`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html) documentation for more info

Comment: still nothing, sorry :(